# WSO2 BPS timer event bpmn

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-business-process

DO you know if it's possible to setup some timer event/task to wait for some time for receiving some action? For example, I need to set up some mechanism where I invoke timer task which waits for example for 10 seconds then I will restart checking process.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a  exists for BPMN which we've used for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `<pick>` It implements the deferred choice workflow pattern, i.e. it can wait for several messages and several timers concurrently. The event that occurs first wins and the contained activity will be executed.

Comment: Yes it will work on the server, however you can execute the same and check